# How to create in Handlebars a helper with more than tow logical operator OR

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, handlebarshelper

I have (valid_payment_nif, valid_personal_nif and valid_iban) and they are boolean. I want to create a helper where can accept 3 options. So far I fount only with 2.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
{{#if valid_payment_nif ||  valid_personal_nif || valid_iban }}
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill"></span>
<span id="gm_valid_payment_nif{{id}}" class="item-status status-check"></span>
{{else}}
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">NIF</span>
<span id="gm_invalid_payment_nif{{id}}" class="item-status status-alert"></span>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: make a function, what have you tried?

Comment: i have try some helpers one of them is:  Handlebars.registerHelper('or', function () {
          // Get function args and remove last one (function name)
          return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, arguments.length - 1).some(Boolean);
      });    But doesn't work. and yes, i have a function. Is where the helper lives .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Handlebars very well but here is a couple of examples depending on how you want to handle input of the vars and/or label its entirely dependent on what you want, there are prob other ways too.

Make a helper which you call and pass your values to, you then can return HTML to be rendered.

Individual statuses with labels:

```
{{{statusCheck this 'valid_payment_nif' 'NIF'}}}
{{{statusCheck this 'valid_personal_nif' 'NIF'}}}
{{{statusCheck this 'valid_iban' 'IBAN'}}}
```

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('statusCheck', function (object, propertyName, labelValue, options) {
    return `<span class="badge badge-${options.lookupProperty(object, propertyName) === true ? 'success' : 'danger'} badge-pill">${labelValue}</span><span id="gm_${propertyName}" class="item-status status-check"></span>`
})
```

Renders:

```
<span class="badge badge-success badge-pill">NIF</span>
<span id="gm_valid_payment_nif" class="item-status status-check"></span>

<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">NIF</span>
<span id="gm_valid_personal_nif" class="item-status status-check"></span>

<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">IBAN</span>
<span id="gm_valid_iban" class="item-status status-check"></span>
```

Or multiple checks for a single status element. Passing in a string of the props to check, then splitting it to get an array:

```
{{{statusCheckSome this 'valid_payment_nif,valid_personal_nif,valid_iban' ''}}}
```

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('statusCheckSome', function (object, propertyNames, labelValue, options) {
  propertyNames = propertyNames.split(',').map(v => v.trim())
  return `
   <span class="badge badge-${propertyNames.some(item => item) ? 'success' : 'danger'} badge-pill">${labelValue}</span>
   <span id="gm_valid" class="item-status status-check"></span>`
})
```

resulting output:

```
<span class="badge badge-success badge-pill"></span>
<span id="gm_valid" class="item-status status-check"></span>
```

Obviously, you're then limited as to what goes in the `id=""`, though I'm not sure why you need it.

or same using JSON as input

```
{{{statusCheckSomeStringified this '["valid_payment_nif", "valid_personal_nif", "valid_iban"]' ''}}}
```

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('statusCheckSomeStringified', function (object, propertyNames, labelValue, options) {
  propertyNames = JSON.parse(propertyNames)
  return `
   <span class="badge badge-${propertyNames.some(item => item) ? 'success' : 'danger'} badge-pill">${labelValue}</span>
   <span id="gm_valid" class="item-status status-check"></span>`
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.. @Lawerence As i am really new probably i didn't explain correctly my needs...  i need this logical operator in order to display in my span an icon status-check or status-alert. So if three of them are true the i need to show 'status-check' otherwise 'status-alert' with the text IBAN or NIf.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option seems to just pass the desired boolean value to whoever is calling the handlebars compiled fragmwnt:

```
info.threeOrs = info.valid_payment_nif ||  info.valid_personal_nif || info.valid_iban;
```

and then in the template use

```
{{#if threeOrs}}
```

Otherwise you can modify the helper function you already have:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("or", function(...args) {
    let i, or = false;
    for (i = 0; i < args.length-1; i++) {
        or = or || args[i];
     }
     // now "or" is the logical OR of the arguments; use it.
     // To return the enclosed block, use args[args.length-1].fn(this).
     return or ? args[args.length-1].fn(this) : '';
});

{{#or valid_payment_nif valid_personal_nif valid_iban}}
Something is true
{{/or}}
```

(See [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/helper-multiple-parameters.html)).

In this case if I pass an array like

```
{ valid_payment_nif: true, valid_personal_nif: true, valid_iban: true }
```

then "Something is true" is returned by the template. If and only if **all** the entries are true, then nothing is returned.

Comment: Hello LSerni and thank you for your time! I tried to do Handlebars.registerHelper but as i am new in Handlebars and in JS is not clear for me How to use it in the view.

Comment: Then I'd start with reading the documentation and trying with simple examples. That will serve you well going forward. Later today I may be able to add and, importantly, *test* the .fn() call that should complete the helper.

Comment: I really appreciate your time! Thank you!

Comment: Done. But I still advise you to check out the documentation from the basics - otherwise you'll just keep having this kind of problems.

Comment: **IF** it works, you should upvote and, optionally, accept the answer (the tick mark on the left) for the next one that might find this question. You may also add how you finally did, as an answer, with the appropriate code, and accept *that*.